# Response from http

Tags: android, http

I am having problem with my code. When I click on button I get message Invalid IP Address, but I really don't know why. Application should fill spinners from MySQL database, but when I press button I get toast that "IP is invalid" and application close.

```
public class IzboraGrada extends Activity {
    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button button, izlaz;
    static String str_grad,str_predmet,url;

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;
    String[] grad, predmet;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_izbora_grada);

        spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        final List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();

        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try
                {

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/test/spinner1.php");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //I think that problem is over here
                Log.e("Fail 1", "3");

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.e("Fail 1", "4");

                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } 

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
             }    

            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray JA=jsonObj.getJSONArray("lista");
                JSONObject json= null;
                grad = new String[JA.length()];       
                predmet = new String[JA.length()];

                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    grad[i] = json.getString("Grad");
                    predmet[i]=json.getString("Predmet");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for(int i=0;i<grad.length;i++)
                {
                    list1.add(grad[i]);
                    list2.add(predmet[i]);
                }

                spinner_fn();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                //login.this.finish();
                }
        }
        });
    }

    private void spinner_fn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, grad);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, predmet);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);


        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinner2.setSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });


    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            spinner1.setSelection(position);

            }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}
```

My PHP, when I start it in localhost, returns this:

```
{"lista":[{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"informatika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"informatika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"engleski"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac","Predmet":"engleski"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"hemija"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac","Predmet":"fizika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"engleski"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"oet"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"oet"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac","Predmet":"tehnicko_crtanje"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"informatika"},{"Grad":"Novi_Sad","Predmet":"matematika"},{"Grad":"Beograd","Predmet":"fizika"},{"Grad":"Kragujevac","Predmet":"francuski"}]}
```

And report from logcat

```
07-29 21:05:35.832: D/dalvikvm(24075): GC_CONCURRENT freed 41K, 6% free 12530K/13319K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 43ms
07-29 21:05:35.832: D/dalvikvm(24075): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
07-29 21:05:35.982: D/libEGL(24075): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
07-29 21:05:35.997: D/libEGL(24075): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-29 21:05:36.002: D/libEGL(24075): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-29 21:05:36.017: D/(24075): Device driver API match
07-29 21:05:36.017: D/(24075): Device driver API version: 10
07-29 21:05:36.017: D/(24075): User space API version: 10 
07-29 21:05:36.017: D/(24075): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
07-29 21:05:36.062: D/OpenGLRenderer(24075): Enabling debug mode 0
07-29 21:05:37.512: E/Fail 1(24075): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-29 21:05:37.592: E/Fail 2(24075): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 21:05:37.592: E/Fail 3(24075): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What exception do you get in logcat?

Comment: Why your network interaction is happening on the main thread? You should move it to an AsyncTask first

Comment: [Don't do networking on the main thread](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr). Also, don't just suppress your exceptions - at least print the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace()`. Finally, [only catch exceptions you're going to handle right then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4406887/264775) or you'll potentially mask more serious issues (like what you've got here).

Comment: Cause I am beginner :) if you can make a code that I have to enter, that would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for help on avoiding networking on the main thread.